# Labels drawn in different order than path lines in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a line graph on which data input will be drawn in a SwiftUI app. The lines are drawn correctly, but I can't seem to group them properly with their respective labels, which are drawn in a different order than the lines (I think?).

Here's where the graph lines are  drawn and the label added:

```
 GeometryReader { r in
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<11) { line in
                Group {
                    let lineFloat = CGFloat(line)
                    let y = CGFloat(r.size.height) * (lineFloat / 10.0)
                    Path { path in
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.size.width, y: y))
                    }.stroke(Color.gray)
                    Text("\(line * 100)W")
                        .offset(x: -r.size.width + 250, y: -y + 10)
                }
            }
```

Which results in a graph that looks like this:

[image: line graph screenshot]

What can be added so that the labels are drawn from the bottom of the graph, with '0W' at the bottom and '1000W' at the top?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `Text`s just under the lines, like now, but the `Text`s in the right order?

Comment: The "0W" should be at the bottom with the ten lines labeled so "1000W" is at the top, where "500W" is now.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI, you want to try avoid using `offset` if possible. The problem here is that the offset means that your first numbers (like `1000W`) are way above the top of the screen, not visible.

Instead you could do a more adaptive layout, and simpler.

In this example, `Array(stride(from: 1000, through: 0, by: -100))` is used to create the wattages. This array will look something like:

```
[1000, 900, 800, 700, ..., 100, 0]
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(stride(from: 1000, through: 0, by: -100)), id: \.self) { wattage in
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 2)

                    Text("\(wattage)W")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading)

                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Lovely. And so much simpler. What can I contain this in other than a ScrollView so that it shrinks to to fit its parent without scrolling?

Comment: @Ja5onHoffman See updated answer (and edit history for changes). It will now try fit everything on at once (but beware for small screens, or landscape orientations)